5+ practicing security personnel held in an island- Everything goes wrong
In this movie, there are 5+ (either) FBI or secret service personnel, who were held in island, where they were suppose to train or it was a training session. The island was an abandoned island, it had paper people, buses, houses, ware house.
As the day passed by, things started getting weird and they were dying one by one. Their deaths were caused by one person who was among them. He uses their weakness and fear to eliminate them, and he occasionally gives them clues as to who will be next, one of his clues was he wrote signs on a glass where it has something to do with light, by writing the speed of light etc etc. One of them was killed by an acid cigarette, as she likes smoking and she saw a cigar pack on the ground, took it and smoked it.
I also recall the culprit was a man, and a woman survived.
In the final event, they both fought and fought and later found themselves in a water (river) where they both were immersed under the water, facing each other, and had their hand up outside the water lever, point a gun at each others direction, and it came down to who can really stay under water the most, as if you suffocate you rise up and you get shot since the other has the drop on you, and that is how he was killed.
The final man standing for a lady.
I do not recall the date, but it has probably been like a decade since I watched it. I think the title starts with a 'D' or 'The'.

Mindhunters (2004)?

Wow, this is like its 5th or 6th appearance on ID. This must be the most rerun movie ever.

@Oliver_C woo!! Thank you that was fast

@Walt really, yes, i didnt see that, Well thanks to you all :)
